# How to create a this HTML layout, by CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am newbie with CSS; so, I do not want to use CSS frameworks.

---

After reading some questions about **fixed header and footer** with CSS (on StackOverflow), I tried to create a HTML layout, as this:

[image: HTML/CSS]

In this layout, both **header** and **menu** are fixed.

---

I have created an HTML file with 2 column: left for menu, right for content. But, it comes with an scrolled-menu:

```css
#menu {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#page {
  width: 66%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  MENU
</div>
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Some content...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

---

When I add this line: `position: fixed;` in `#menu`, the layout will be broken. Could help help me to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Currently you could use the Tag directly as `<header> <body> <footer>` you need to establish `position : block`. I would like to recommend that you uses a Framework like Bootstrap, today is commonly uses for design webpages, if you are new un webpages it Will be useful for you

http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: You can check this http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-grid-examples.php, there hace many examples with code

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 2 Unequal Column Layout for Tablets and Desktops</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .row > div{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .header{
        min-height: 90px;
    }
    .footer{
        min-height: 60px;
    }
    .header, .footer{
        background: #2f2f2f;
    }
    .sidebar{
        background: #dbdfe5;
    }
    .content{
        background: #b4bac0;
    }
    .sidebar, .content{
        min-height: 300px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Open the output in a new blank tab (Click the arrow next to "Show Output" button) and resize the browser window to understand how the Bootstrap responsive grid system works. -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="header"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="sidebar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```